# Calling a custom method from the manipulation at delete node vis.js

Tags: angular, vis.js-network

I am trying to use vis.js (v4.21.0) with Angular (v4.2.4).

I want to call a custom method before deleting the node, so I added a method to delete node in manipulation, but I am unable to call my custom method from it.

`My-component.ts`

```ts
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit {

private graphData: any;
private options: any;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
let nodeList = new Vis.DataSet([
  {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
  {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
  {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
  {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
  {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
]);

// create an array with edges
let edgeList = new Vis.DataSet([
  {from: 1, to: 3},
  {from: 1, to: 2},
  {from: 2, to: 4},
  {from: 2, to: 5}
]);
this.graphData = {nodes: nodeList, edges: edgeList};

this.options = {
manipulation: {
  enabled: true,
  initiallyActive: false,
  addNode: true,
  addEdge: true,
  editEdge: true,
  deleteNode: function(nodeData,callback) {
    this.deleteNodeFunction(nodeData); // defined below
     `here getting issue ''this'' is not defined.`
  },
  deleteEdge: true,
}
};

let network;

try {
 const container = document.getElementById('test');
  network = new Vis.Network(container, this.graphData, this.options);

}catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message)
}
}

deleteNodeFunction(nodeData){
// do something here 
// may be call some other method.
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
deleteNode: function(nodeData,callback) {
  this.deleteNodeFunction(nodeData); // defined below
}.bind(this),
```

What's happening is that when Vis.js goes to call your `deleteNode()` method, it's calling it with its own context, so `this` is now referring to the network rather than your MyComponentComponent instance. The network has no `deleteNodeFunction()` method, so nothing happens.

Calling `.bind(this)` should prevent the issue. Alternatively, you could use an arrow function, which has automatic binding:

```
deleteNode: (nodeData,callback) => {
  this.deleteNodeFunction(nodeData); // defined below
},
```